# How to change the color of points only (not the lines) in scatterplotMatrix in R?

Tags: r, colors, scatter-plot

I have a scatterplot with many variables, and need to control the color of only the points in the scatterplot, but to leave the lines as they are colored. I have

```
scatterplotMatrix(~y+x1+x2+x3+x4, data=dataset, cex=.5,col=rgb(0,100,0,50,maxColorValue=255))
```

The above code changes the color of both the points and the regression lines, which I don't want..

Any help please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't tell us what package `scatterplotMatrix` is in.

If it is the one in the `car` package then it looks like the `col` argument will take 3 colors with the first 2 specifying the colors for lines and the 3rd for the points.  So if you change your call to have a vector with 3 colors (with the 3rd being the value that you want the points to be) then it should work.

If a different function is being used then you need to tell us more.

Here is a quick example (since we don't have your data):

```
scatterplotMatrix( ~Sepal.Width+Sepal.Length+Petal.Width+Petal.Length,
 data=iris, col=c('purple','blue','black') )
```

The character strings that I used for colors can be replaced with calls to `rgb`.

Comment: hi Greg, yes, it's the 'car' library. So, where/how should I enter the 3-elements vector in: col=rgb(0,100,0,50,maxColorValue=255) ??

Comment: @OliverAmundsen, see my example and just wrap `c()` around three calls to `rgb` or put in the string values returned by `rgb`.